# Merging two scripts - Check if image and size before preview

Tags: jquery

I've been attempting to merge the following two scripts into one whereas upon the file chosen to be uploaded is of the correct file type and file size;

**Script One:**

**HTML**

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <input type='file' id="imgInp" />
    <img id="blah" src="#" alt="your image" />
</form>
```

**JQuery**

```
function readURL(input) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function (e) {
            $('#blah').attr('src', e.target.result);
        }
        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
}
$("#imgInp").change(function(){
    readURL(this);
});
```

**JSFiddle** http://jsfiddle.net/LvsYc/

**Script Two:**

```
function (e, data) {
    var goUpload = true;
    var uploadFile = data.files[0];
    if (!(/\.(gif|jpg|jpeg|tiff|png)$/i).test(uploadFile.name)) {
        common.notifyError('You must select an image file only');
        goUpload = false;
    }
    if (uploadFile.size > 2000000) { // 2mb
        common.notifyError('Please upload a smaller image, max size is 2 MB');
        goUpload = false;
    }
    if (goUpload == true) {
        data.submit();
    }
},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/6n7Lqrq7/)

```
function readURL(input) {
  if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
    var goUpload = true;
    var uploadFile = input.files[0];
    if (!(/\.(gif|jpg|jpeg|tiff|png)$/i).test(uploadFile.name)) {
      common.notifyError('You must select an image file only');
      goUpload = false;
    }
    if (uploadFile.size > 2000000) { // 2mb
      common.notifyError('Please upload a smaller image, max size is 2 MB');
      goUpload = false;
    }
    if (goUpload) {
      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = function (e) {
        $('#blah').attr('src', e.target.result);
        setTimeout(function() {
          input.form.submit();
        },5000); // give them time to see the image
      }
      reader.readAsDataURL(uploadFile);
    }
  }
}

$("#imgInp").change(function(){
  readURL(this);
});
```

---

**Update**

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/02662san/)

```
var wrapper = $('<div/>').css({
    height: 0,
    width: 0,
    'overflow': 'hidden'
});
var fileInput = $(':file').wrap(wrapper);

fileInput.change(function () {
    readURL(this);
})

$('#file').click(function () {
    fileInput.click();
}).show();

function readURL(input) {
    $('#blah').hide();
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var goUpload = true;
        var uploadFile = input.files[0];
        if (!(/\.(gif|jpg|jpeg|tiff|png)$/i).test(uploadFile.name)) {
            $('#file').text('You must select an image file only');
            setTimeout(function () {
                $('#file').text('Choose file');
            }, 2000);
            goUpload = false;
        }
        if (uploadFile.size > 2000000) { // 2mb
            common.notifyError('Please upload a smaller image, max size is 2 MB');
            goUpload = false;
        }
        if (goUpload) {
            $('#file').text("Uploading " + uploadFile.name);
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function (e) {
                $('#blah').attr('src', e.target.result).show();
                setTimeout(function () {
                    input.form.submit();
                }, 5000); // give them time to see the image
            }
            reader.readAsDataURL(uploadFile);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @mplungjan. Just made a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y90ow5px/) however it allows any file upload and no longer displays the image.

Comment: Fixed it. I passed event but it is not needed

Comment: The previewing of the image now works however this allows me to upload my index.html file. Where it says "No file chosen" uploading my .htnl it'll say "index.html"

Comment: I do not understand what you mean.

Comment: When you click to upload a file it tells you the file name. Upon choosing a file I have "index.html" it shows here meaning this still allows other than image files to be uploaded. 'You must select an image file only' is meant to display.

Comment: common.notifyError is some kind of Knockoutjs script - in my fiddle, selecting anything not an image does nothing. If I select an image I see it and 5 secs later it is sent. You can expose the goUpload to the submit or invalidate a submit button which you have not shown in your code

Comment: [This Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7dkh4hxw/) is what I plan to attempt to merge this script with. Although I've marked this as the answer, would you mind helping changing the value in the div to display the error message?

Comment: Thank you very much. If it helps, I'm doing this website for my own start-up charity :)